# Docker Compose Flags

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I don't how to run the docker-compose equivalent of my code

```
docker run -d --name=server --restart=always --net network --ip 172.18.0.5 -p 5003:80 -v $APP_PHOTO_DIR:/app/mysql-data -v $APP_CONFIG_DIR:/app/config webserver
```

I've done this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    image: app-dependencies
    ports:
     - "5003:80"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command:  python /app/app.py
    restart: always
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.5
```

Comment: What's going wrong?  Syntactically, at a first glance, what you show looks fine.

Comment: I don't know this flag: --net network_name

Comment: That’s equivalent to the `networks: {app_net: }` that you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need an IP address for container? It is not recommended practice, why do you want to set it explicitly?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:   # correct, this would be container's name
    image: webserver  # this should be image name from your command line
    ports:
     - "5003:80"  # correct, but only if you need to communicate to service from ouside
    volumes:  # volumes just repeat you command line, you can use Env vars
      - $APP_PHOTO_DIR:/app/mysql-data
      - $APP_CONFIG_DIR:/app/config
    command:  ["python", "/app/app.py"]  # JSON notation strongly recommended
    restart: always
```

Then `docker-compose up -d` and that's it. You can access your service from host with `localhost:5003`, no need for internal IP.

Comment: I need a staitc IP to connect to database

Comment: If database is your service, you connect to it using your **hosts** ip and port `5003`

Answer (score 0):

For networks, I always include in the docker-compose file, the network specification. If the network already exists, docker will not create a new one.

```
version: '3'
services:
   server:
      image: app-dependencies
   ports:
      - "5003:80"
   volumes:
      - ./app:/app
   command:  python /app/app.py
   restart: always
   networks:
     app_net:
       ipv4_address: 172.18.0.5

networks:
  app_net:
     name: NETWORK_NAME
     driver: bridge
     ipam:
       config:
          - subnet: NETWORK_SUBNET

volumes:
   VOLUME_NAME:
      driver:local
```

And you will need to add the volumes separately to match the docker run command.

Comment: Docker Compose will create a default network for you if you don’t specify one.  As @grapes notes in their answer, explicitly setting container and network IP addresses tends to be discouraged (the addresses are hard to maintain, Docker DNS avoids the need to know them, and it prevents you from duplicating the YAML file).